# Search for a specific url and retreive the column data across that url

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have an excel sheet in which the first column contain the url's and next to each url there are some columns.I have to search for a specific url from the 1st column and then read all the column data(some urls have 2 columns some have 3 columns and so on...) for the url that is being searched.

**ExcelSheet:**

```
       **Col1           Col2    Col3      Col4**
Row1   www.mytest1.com  John    Stephens  23 
Row2   www.mytest2.com  Ricky   Martin
Row3   www.mytest3.com  Rocky

def search_url_in_column1("https://www.mytest.com"):
    wb = load_workbook('Test.xlsx') #Load the workbook
    ws = wb['Sheet1'] #Load the worksheet
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, value_only=True): if row[1].value = search_term: break`

Answer (score -1):

This can be done easily using `pandas`. If you don't have pandas installed, you can install it using `pip install pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(***Excel file path***) # Storing the excel file in a variable as a dataframe

desired_data = df[df["Col1"] == "www.mytest1.com"] # Getting all rows who have the *Col1* value equal to *www.mytest1.com*.
```

Output-

|  | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | www.mytest1.com | John | Stephens | 23.0 |

---

If you want to do this using `opepyxl` use the code below,

```
import openpyxl as xl

def search_url(searched_val):
  wb = xl.load_workbook(***workbook location***)
  sheet = wb["Sheet1"]

  all_rows = list(sheet.iter_rows())[1:]

  for row in all_rows:
    if row[0].value == searched_val:
      return [val.value for val in row]
      break

search_url("www.mytest1.com")
```

Output -

```
['www.mytest1.com', 'John', 'Stephens', 23]
```

Comment: I have to use openpyxl library not pandas as this library is been used in the framework eveywhere

Comment: This includes unused variables. Why do you convert rows to a list? And why not use `values_only`? I also think that it's wasteful to open the workbook within the function.

Comment: My bad! I was using a different approach to retrieve the cell values using the column and row indices earlier and forgot to remove the variables used in that method. I opened the workbook inside the function itself because John himself had it written that way. What do you mean by `values_only`?